# Hibernate cannot resolve the field list for one of the sub-classes - Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4.3 with JDK 1.8. I have defined two entity classes `Purchase` and `Payment`, first inheriting from the abstract `StuffTransaction` which is in turn a subclass of `Transaction`, and the second, i.e. `Payment`, is a direct subclass of `Transaction`. All of theses classes have the two properties of "deptor" and "creditor", defined as follows:

```
@Entity(name = "ac_transactions")
public abstract class Transaction implements Serializable, Comparable<Transaction>, Data {

    protected long id;
    protected String title;
    ...

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -952911952174854827L;


    @ManyToOne
    public abstract Account getDeptor();
    @ManyToOne
    public abstract Account getCreditor();
    public abstract void setDeptor(Account a);
    public abstract void setCreditor(Account a);

    ...
}
```

and:

```
public abstract class StuffTransaction extends Transaction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9002942588702189794L;

    ...
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class Purchase extends StuffTransaction {

    private transient Person buyer, seller;

    @Override
    public void setDeptor(Account a) {
        buyer = (Person) a;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreditor(Account a) {
        seller = (Person) a;
    }

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Person getDeptor() {
        return buyer;
    }

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false) 
    public Person getCreditor() {
        return seller;
    }

    ...
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class Payment extends Transaction {

    private transient Account sink;
    private transient Account source;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Person getDeptor() {
        return (Person) sink;
    }

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Person getCreditor() {
        return (Person) source;
    }

    private transient Transaction concern;

    @OneToOne
    public Transaction getConcern() {
        return concern;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can see that everything is logically the same between `Purchase` and `Payment`. And my table is created this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `ac_transactions` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`dsc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`val` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`opponentName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`deptor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`creditor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`visible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`DTYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`valueChangePercentageChain` tinyblob,
`type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`salePoint` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`confirmed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`concern_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=108 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But the problem is that the following statements are not behaving the same way:

```
getSession().get(Purchase.class, id);
```

.vs.

```
getSession().get(Payment.class, id);
```

where `getSession()` is defined so that it opens a new or returns a previously opened session. The first statement works perfectly, but the second throws the following exception:

```
INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at aaserver.ConnectionThread.run(ConnectionThread.java:111)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4120)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:467)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1066)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2540)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:951)
        at aaserver.DataUnit$Transactions.getPayment(DataUnit.java:347)
        at aaserver.DataUnit$Transactions.get(DataUnit.java:353)
        at aaserver.ConnectionThread.deleteDocs(ConnectionThread.java:307)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'transactio3_.creditor' in 'field list'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
        ... 26 more
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
        at util.Toolkit.readObject(Toolkit.java:222)
        at aaserver.ServerFrame.main(ServerFrame.java:1101)
```

The SQL generated for the two statements of course differ. For the first, I have:

```
select purchase0_.id as id2_3_0_, purchase0_.creditor_id as credito15_3_0_, purchase0_.day as day3_3_0_, purchase0_.month as month4_3_0_, purchase0_.year as year5_3_0_, purchase0_.deptor_id as deptor_16_3_0_, purchase0_.dsc as dsc6_3_0_, purchase0_.opponentName as opponent7_3_0_, purchase0_.title as title8_3_0_, purchase0_.val as val9_3_0_, purchase0_.visible as visible10_3_0_, purchase0_.confirmed as confirm11_3_0_, purchase0_.salePoint as salePoi12_3_0_, purchase0_.type as type13_3_0_, purchase0_.valueChangePercentageChain as valueCh14_3_0_, account1_.id as id2_4_1_, account1_.dsc as dsc3_4_1_, account1_.groupName as groupNam4_4_1_, account1_.name as name5_4_1_, account1_.visible as visible6_4_1_, account1_.currentCap as currentC7_4_1_, account1_.workHour as workHour8_4_1_, account1_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_4_1_, account2_.id as id2_4_2_, account2_.dsc as dsc3_4_2_, account2_.groupName as groupNam4_4_2_, account2_.name as name5_4_2_, account2_.visible as visible6_4_2_, account2_.currentCap as currentC7_4_2_, account2_.workHour as workHour8_4_2_, account2_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_4_2_ from ac_transactions purchase0_ left outer join accounts account1_ on purchase0_.creditor_id=account1_.id left outer join accounts account2_ on purchase0_.deptor_id=account2_.id where purchase0_.id=? and purchase0_.DTYPE='Purchase'
```

and for the second:

```
select payment0_.id as id2_3_0_, payment0_.creditor_id as credito15_3_0_, payment0_.day as day3_3_0_, payment0_.month as month4_3_0_, payment0_.year as year5_3_0_, payment0_.deptor_id as deptor_16_3_0_, payment0_.dsc as dsc6_3_0_, payment0_.opponentName as opponent7_3_0_, payment0_.title as title8_3_0_, payment0_.val as val9_3_0_, payment0_.visible as visible10_3_0_, payment0_.concern_id as concern19_3_0_, account1_.id as id2_4_1_, account1_.dsc as dsc3_4_1_, account1_.groupName as groupNam4_4_1_, account1_.name as name5_4_1_, account1_.visible as visible6_4_1_, account1_.currentCap as currentC7_4_1_, account1_.workHour as workHour8_4_1_, account1_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_4_1_, account2_.id as id2_4_2_, account2_.dsc as dsc3_4_2_, account2_.groupName as groupNam4_4_2_, account2_.name as name5_4_2_, account2_.visible as visible6_4_2_, account2_.currentCap as currentC7_4_2_, account2_.workHour as workHour8_4_2_, account2_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_4_2_, transactio3_.id as id2_3_3_, transactio3_.creditor_id as credito15_3_3_, transactio3_.day as day3_3_3_, transactio3_.month as month4_3_3_, transactio3_.year as year5_3_3_, transactio3_.deptor_id as deptor_16_3_3_, transactio3_.dsc as dsc6_3_3_, transactio3_.opponentName as opponent7_3_3_, transactio3_.title as title8_3_3_, transactio3_.val as val9_3_3_, transactio3_.visible as visible10_3_3_, transactio3_.creditor as credito17_3_3_, transactio3_.deptor as deptor18_3_3_, transactio3_.concern_id as concern19_3_3_, transactio3_.confirmed as confirm11_3_3_, transactio3_.salePoint as salePoi12_3_3_, transactio3_.type as type13_3_3_, transactio3_.valueChangePercentageChain as valueCh14_3_3_, transactio3_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_3_3_ from ac_transactions payment0_ left outer join accounts account1_ on payment0_.creditor_id=account1_.id left outer join accounts account2_ on payment0_.deptor_id=account2_.id left outer join ac_transactions transactio3_ on payment0_.concern_id=transactio3_.id where payment0_.id=? and payment0_.DTYPE='Payment'
```

And this second one runs into error.
I don't think that there is a problem with my Hibernate config since everything is working very well, except for this case.
Any idea?

EDIT: I added the SQL generated for both cases.

EDIT 2: Added some more detail about `Payment` definition.

Comment: The Problem might be the @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false), would be helpful to see the generated SQL though...

Comment: @tom I added the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL shows that it's trying to access

```
transactio3_.creditor
```

where transactio3 is the alias for ac_transactions

```
ac_transactions transactio3_
```

There's no field creditor in the table, hence the error.

There is an additional outer-join in the second SQL-Statement that's causing the Problem, so the mappings aren't equal.

Edit:

The Mapping

```
@OneToOne
public Transaction getConcern() {
    return concern;
}
```

should either have a mappedBy attribute or additional @JoinColumn-Mapping (not sure which is right in your case as the Transaction-Class doesn't show the other end of the relationship)

So either

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "creditor_id")
```

or

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "transaction")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're right. There is no "creditor" but a "creditor_id" that works when called as "payment0_.creditor_id" in the same SQL. I updated the `Payment` definition in my question so that you can see why Hibernate needs the "transactio3_.creditor" thing. But how can I tell it to recognize it as a "transactio3_.creditor_id" instead, in order to fix the error?